# Best way in minimizing size of vector svg file

Tags: xml, svg, compression, adobe-illustrator

I have a 1 megabyte vector svg file that I created with Adobe Illustrator. Any tips on how I can reduce the file size?

I tried running it through Contenta Converter, but it converted it from a vector to a raster image.  Unfortunately I can't use a compressed svg file either.

Here is the file if it helps anyone: http://d.pr/Qh6T

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image seems to consist of a repeated pattern, however, in the source code each instance of the pattern is written out in full. That's what's making it large.

Since versions CS2 and newer have [excellent SVG support](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/51294), the most likely reason it's being written this way is because you're using copy and paste rather than Illustrator's patterns. This [tutorial](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/illustrator/ss/sf_patterns_9.htm) is a good explanation on how to do this.

Comment: Hey Chris,  I know this is old, but any ideas why after I make them into patterns they show up as blank files when I view them in a browser?